# Input binding not working on custom made angular library when used in application

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have a problem trying to use my library from other component different of appcomponent because when I use the selector from other component I got input variables are undefined

MyLibComponent.ts

```
export class MyLibComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() jsonData: string= '';
  ngOnInit(): void {

    console.log("contructor ", this.jsonData)
  }
}
```

In the Application where I want to use myLib, I import the module

AppModule.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MyLibModule } from 'MyLib';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MyLibExampleComponent } from './components/my-lib-example/my-lib-example.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyLibExampleComponent,
   
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MyLibModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have a routing path:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'jsontest', component: MyLibComponent }
];
```

and in the MyLibExample.component.html:

```
<p>my-lib-example works!</p>
<lib-MyLib jsonData='{
    "boolean": true,
    "color": "gold"}></lib-MyLib>
```

in the MyLibExample.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-lib-example',
  templateUrl: './my-lib-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-lib-example.component.css']
})
export class MyLibExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

No matter what a try I still got the jsonData Input Variable undefined on the console log. Only if I use the selector directly in the app.component.html I got the jsonData with the correct values.

Tree for the monorepo:

```
--dist
-----MyLib
--projects
-----MyLib
--src
-----app
```

Comment: In <lib-MyLib> are you assigning the "jsonData" input statically or programmatically? Because if you assign it directly in the html as you're showing, the Input shouldn't be undefined in the ngOnInit. Instead, if you set it programmatically, in the ngOnInit this input can be undefined. You can try, instead, to make a "setInput". You can do as follows: `@Input('jsonData') set jsonData(value: string) { ...run code everytime data changes... }`

Comment: I follow your indications but it still not work if I implement the lib-selector on the MyLibExample.component.html, but if I try to put the selector on the app.component.html I got to run the code every time data changes.

Comment: Could you try to share a running snipped code on stackblitz?